# Avoid grey background on IE 10 anchors / links

Tags: css, styles, anchor, internet-explorer-10

How do you avoid the annoying grey background that IE 10 applies to anchors when you click them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is actually a really easy CSS fix. IE 10 changes the `background-color` of anchor tags when they are in the [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:active) state. To stop it from happening or to change the colour you can use the CSS rule below.

```
a:active{
    background-color: transparent; /* Can be any colour, not just transparent */
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/NtjK7/

On a side note, it's worth mentioning that when styling links you need to ensure that you write the rules in the correct order to ensure that previous styles don't get overwritten:

```
a:link{}    /* 1st */
a:visited{} /* 2nd */
a:hover{}   /* 3rd */
a:active{}  /* 4th */
```

Comment: Much better than the fix I've found.

Comment: Obviously need to be careful if your anchor does actually have a background colour on it as you will get a flash of the colour behind it whilst you click

Answer (score 4):

I found it was actually :focus that added the grey background.

this worked for me:

```
a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: A combination of the above answer, and @tw16's answer (further above) resolved the issue completely for me.  I had to do this to get IE11 on Windows 8.1 to behave properly:

`a:focus,
a:active`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find many information but I did found one fix:

**Wrap the text of the anchor in a `span`**

[Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/5ZhXA/)

If you don't want to change every anchor in your HTML you can use a script like this one:

```
$("a:not(.dont-use-span)").each(function() {
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
});
```

[Working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/5ZhXA/1/)

*Note: just add the class `dont-use-span` to the anchors that you don't want to modify*

Answer (score 0):

After many unfructuous tests, I finally made it works with this :

```
  a               {color:#fff; background-color:#f77927 !important;}
  a:hover         {color:#fff; background-color:#e65e06 !important;}
  a.active        {color:#fff; background-color:#e65e06 !important;}
  a.focus         {color:#fff; background-color:#e65e06 !important;}
```

[See in action](http://jsfiddle.net/avudzpvv/)